# Grab data from a text file in PHP

Tags: php

I coded a script in C# which has the ability to grab data from a specific string in a text file, for example:

Program grabs the description of a chosen badge:

> badge_desc_BADGEID=This is the data that's going to get grabbed

Although I am not sure how to go about doing this in PHP, because I want it to be able to grab the description of the chosen badge ID. In C# it's the method of replacing, splitting and then replacing the string again, but I'm not sure how to do this in PHP, like I've stated.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: 1. use google/search SO; 2. use databases.

Comment: I would use databases, but the file is used for other reasons aswell which can't be accessed by a database.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like an ini file?

Php have a function to parse ini files, the problem is that you can't save.

http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.parse-ini-file.php

Anyway, take a look to [Config_Lite](http://pear.php.net/package/Config_Lite/) pear package that can handle and save ini like files.